# How do you put a "LIKE" button on your Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

Every post on here seems to be directed to Advanced Users, I just want to know simply how to place a "Like Button" on my Facebook page? Where do I put the HTML code thats generated for me?

Comment: Are you talking about adding a like button to your Facebook page on your website (the [Like Box social plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) is your answer) or add a like button on your Facebook page ? Please be more specific and give us more details.

Answer (score 1):

Use [lint](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), place your link there and at the bottom you'll have iFrame code. You'll place it to your website (anywhere) and you're done